# Team Foundation Server 2015 Upgrade / Migration

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I currently have 2 x TFS servers running (2013 update 3 & 2013 Update 2). I wish to migrate / upgrade to new hardware but only run once instance of TFS 2015 & One instance of SQL. Currently both TFS Servers use seperate 2012 SQL Servers (4 servers in total - i wish to half to the footprint).

New hardware will be Windows Servers 2012r2 & 2014 SQL Server.

I have performed migrationgs to new hardware before but only for the same Team foundation server - i.e i use the same tsf_config database and peform a upgrade on all databases. Does anyone have any links / advice on how to perform this, both current production TFS Servers have multiple Project Collections - also adds to the complexitity.

Thank you for any help / guidance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like link only answers, but there's a very detailed MSDN article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd936138(v=vs.120).aspx) that goes through the process.